# svn --set-depth still updates directories that were set "empty"

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

In my organization, we have a sizeable `branch` directory where everybody's branches live. I'm only interested in updating my branches (with `svn up`).
So I did:

```
svn ls | xargs -L 1 svn up --set-depth empty
```

in the directory and the plan is, to mark the branches I'm interested in with `svn --set-depth infinity MyBranch`.  but if I do an `svn up` after setting all sub directories to `--set-depth empty`, it still truies to update one of them, why are they not excluded now?